# C++ inserting wchar_t backslash into string

Tags: c++, string, escaping, string-literals

I have a wide char literal:

```
const wchar_t* charSet =  L" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?\n"
                                L"@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_\n"
                           L"`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~\n";
```

When I pass it into text processor '\'(backslash) isn't there.Now if I put instead \\ it

I am getting compile time error:

> "missing closing quote"

So how do I put backslash into such a char string?

Answer (score 3):

As for your original code

```
L" !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?\n"
```

you simply missed escaping the quote character `"` again. Adding another `\` you'll get

```
L" !\\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?\n"
```

and the now unescaped `"` closes the literal at this point. The next occurrence of `"` will open a new literal but it's unbalanced, hence the compiler error message (you can spot the effect even in the code markup here). You need to add a further `\` to escape the `"` again:

```
L" !\\\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?\n"
//  ^^^ Fix this
```

---

But managing escaped characters intermixed with `\` backslash and `"` quote characters is pretty hard to read and to maintain with changes.

Since the latest standard ([c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)) you can make use of [*raw character string literals*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::wstring ws(LR"del( !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?)del" L"\n"
                    LR"del(@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_)del" L"\n"
                    LR"del(`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~)del" L"\n");
    std::wcout << ws;
    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
 !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?
@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_
`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

No *escaping* necessary, you see.

See the working samples [here](http://ideone.com/M3c05B) and [here](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/TzPj) for compilers supporting the current standards.

Comment: But you didn't put a backslash like this:  !\"#   Your backslash seems to be skipped as well.Or you didn't insert it?

Comment: @MichaelIV I think i unintentionally removed it, should work fine when you put one in (see the backslash near the end of the second output line). I fixed the sample and the code in the answer. You can also [create a fork](http://ideone.com/fork/M3c05B) from the online sample and play around with it, until it fits your needs.

Comment: Under which compiler does it work? on MSVC 110 it still throws "missing closing quote"

Comment: @MichaelIV Note I mentioned _'the latest standard'_. I think at least MSVC 2012 should support it right (the raw character literal solution). The other solution regarding your original code, with correctly escaped backslash **and** escaped `"` quote character, should work with any older compiler versions. Did you check the running online example also?

Comment: Yes,I did but copy = pasting it into VS 2012 causes compilation error I reported above.

Comment: @MichaelIV With `-std=c++11` option set? I think it's not the default for VS2012 IIRC.

Comment: @MichaelIV OK, at least using [this VS2013 online compiler](http://rise4fun.com/Vcpp/TzPj) both of the sample codes are well accepted. Do you want to tag your question [tag:visual-studio-2012]?

Comment: @MichaelIV As from this [supported C++11 feature list for the VS compiler versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#corelanguagetable) in fact VS2012 doesn't support the _raw string literal_ at all. Though following the advice I give in 1st place now, should work.